# EE2 + PHP 7 + Low Variables = Possible?

Tags: low-variables, low

Wondering if anyone has had success running EE2 and Low Variables on PHP 7?  I saw that Low made LV3 compatible with PHP 7.  (http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables/changelog).  But it seems LV2 is still stuck on PHP 5.

What has to happen to make it all work?

Answer (score 0):

What has to happen is probably that I have to make the EE2 version PHP7 compatible. That's not planned as of yet, but given enough demand, that can change.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  But I know how it goes.  No worries.  Thanks.